# Set vertical text by Script adobe after effects

Tags: adobe, after-effects

I have set text like this below.

```
var myTextLayer = mainComposition.layers.addText();
var textProp = myTextLayer.property("Source Text");
textDoc = textProp.value;
textDoc.text = 'my test text';
textProp.setValueAtTime(0,textDoc);
```

I want to set text as `vertical text`, However I couldn't find attribute [here](http://aejsx.hiroshisaito.net/textdocument-object/attributes).

Is there any other property I can check???

I appreciate any help or hint.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programatically, you can split the text at each character and then join it back with carriage returns:

```
let textSource = value;
let newText = textSource.split("").join("\n");
newText;
```

Or, in one line of code:

```
value.split("").join("\n");
```

Or easier...use the vertical text tool:

[image]

Comment: Thank you but Somehow it doesn't work at `split("")`

Comment: split('') doesn't work though , but basic idea just adding \n for each letter works.

Comment: You're right @whitebear  I hadn't tested that code.  
This is one line of code that works:

value.split("").join("\n");

I edited my original answer with valid code.